# Can you define a files.include setting like the files.exclude setting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a directory structure like so

```
/
| /node
| | index.js
| | /node_modules
| | | /localModule
| | | | index.js
| /node_modules
| | /npmModule
```

and the problem is I want all node/**/node_modules directories to be indexed and searchable, but due to the default ignoring of node_modules directories, I can't get my wanted node_modules folders included in indexing, is there a way to set a `files.include` rule the way you can do `files.exclude`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in settings hover over the line with `**/node_modules` on it and at the end of the line you can click the little `x` at the end of the ;line to remove that item from the `search.exclude` settings.  That will result in this setting:

```
"search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": false
},
```

Alternatively, you can just add the `search.exclude` entry above to your settings manually with the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment, "files.include" is not supported by the [workspace file schema](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_workspace-file-schema). Vscode says "Unknown configuration setting" when I tried that.

But you can simply add files by defining them under the "folders" directive like this:

```json
{
  "folders": [
    {
      // Source code
      "name": "Product",
      "path": "vscode"
    },
    {
      // Docs and release notes
      "name": "Documentation",
      "path": "vscode-docs"
    },
    {
      // Yeoman extension generator
      "name": "Extension generator",
      "path": "vscode-generator-code"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: VS Code gives me "Unknown configuration setting" for this as well